# Puppet notice: current_value absent, should be present

Tags: puppet, users, groups, home-directory

I'm trying to add a user via puppet (v 3.2.4), and get this notice on --noop:

> Notice: /Stage[main]/Usergroup/Group[user_one]/ensure: current_value
>   absent, should be present (noop)

Here's my manifest:

```
# usersgroups
class usergroup {

  group { "user_one":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 500,
  }
  group { "dev_website_1":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 501,
  }
  group { "dev_website_2":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 502,
  }

  user { "user_one":
      ensure => present,
      uid => 500,
      gid => 500,
      groups => ["dev_website_1", "dev_website_2"]
  }

}
include usergroup
```

Should I replace "ensure => present" with "current_value => present"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message means puppet detected that group doesn't exist (current_value absent) and wants to create it (should be present) but won't because you are running with --noop. It is just info, your config is fine :)

You should end with something like

```
user {'user_one':
    uid        => 1234,
    gid        => 1234,
    managehome => true,
    password   => sha1-encoded-pass (as in /etc/shadow)
}
```

[User Resource](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#user)